# Tornado testing async requests

Tags: python, unit-testing, tornado

I need an advice regards testing tornado app. For now I just playing with demo chat application, but it looks like real-life problem.

In the handler I have:

```
class MessageUpdatesHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def post(self):
        cursor = self.get_argument("cursor", None)
        global_message_buffer.wait_for_messages(self.on_new_messages,
                                                cursor=cursor)

    def on_new_messages(self, messages):
        # Closed client connection
        if self.request.connection.stream.closed():
            return
        self.finish(dict(messages=messages))


class MessageBuffer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ....

    def wait_for_messages(self, callback, cursor=None):
        if cursor:
            new_count = 0
           for msg in reversed(self.cache):
                if msg["id"] == cursor:
                    break
                new_count += 1
            if new_count:
                callback(self.cache[-new_count:])
                return
        self.waiters.add(callback)

    def cancel_wait(self, callback):
        .....

    def new_messages(self, messages):
        logging.info("Sending new message to %r listeners", len(self.waiters))
        for callback in self.waiters:
            try:
                callback(messages)
            except:
                logging.error("Error in waiter callback", exc_info=True)
        self.waiters = set()
        self.cache.extend(messages)
        if len(self.cache) > self.cache_size:
            self.cache = self.cache[-self.cache_size:]
```

As I metioned full source code is in [torndado demos](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/chat/chatdemo.py)

In my test I have:

```
@wsgi_safe
class MessageUpdatesHandlerTest(LoginedUserHanldersTest):
    Handler = MessageUpdatesHandler

    def test_add_message(self):
        from chatdemo import global_message_buffer
        kwargs = dict(
            method="POST",
            body='',
        )
        future = self.http_client.fetch(self.get_url('/'), callback=self.stop, **kwargs)
        message = {
        "id": '123',
        "from": "first_name",
        "body": "hello",
        "html": "html"
        }
        global_message_buffer.new_messages([message])
        response = self.wait()
        self.assertEqual(response.code, 200)
        self.mox.VerifyAll()
```

What happens:

1. It creates a future object
2. It sends a hello message, in this moment no `waiter` is registered
   in `MessageBuffer` so callback is not called
3. In `wait` starts IoLoop and makes, a post fetch and `waiter` becomes
   registered in `MessageBuffer`
4. Callback is never called and my response remains empty, so
   everything fails with

   AssertionError: Async operation timed out
       after 5 seconds

What I want it to do:

1. On post register itself as a waiter
2. Receive some messages
3. Return to me a 200 response

Thank you for your help